# Sorting data in bootstrap table (datafield issue)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

So I have a react bootstrap table (very simplified version):

```
<BootstrapTable data={gameData}>
  <TableHeaderColumn dataField="player">
    Player username
  </TableHeaderColumn>
  <TableHeaderColumn dataField="games">
    Game1 score
  </TableHeaderColumn>
  <TableHeaderColumn datafield="games">
    Game2 score
  </TableHeaderColumn>
  <TableHeaderColumn datafield="total">
    Total score
  </TableHeaderColumn>
</BootstrapTable>
```

And I have data coming from somewhere like this:

```
{
"player" : "playerName",
"games": {
    "game1": "10",
    "game2": "15",
}
"total" : "25"
}
```

I want to be able to sort the table, and to do so each tableheader needs to have it's own datafield. I am able to sort player, and total score since they have their own datafield, but I am not able to sort games score. I tried this:

```
 datafield="games.game1">
 datafield="games.game2">
```

But it does not work. I am really new to react, so is there any way I can solve this problem?

Thanks for the help

Comment: have you tried it by adding dataFormat={showGame1} after the datafield attribute, and then adding following function 'function showGame1(cell, row) {
  return cell.game1;
}' With this you should be able to get nested fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-bootstrap-table` doesn't support the nested data field. but `react-bootstrap-table-next` it does. you can check this [demo](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Work%20on%20Columns&selectedStory=Display%20Nested%20Data&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel) and also [this](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/column-props.html#columndatafield-required-string).

I think you can consider to use `react-bootstrap-table-next`. [here](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/) is the official website :)

Comment: I have already solved this problem by creating  a javascript function that flattens the object, so that there are no nested objects/children, but then sorting is the next problem I have.

Comment: @JohnDoeveto about the sorting problem I think the only way to fix is custom a sort function by yourself.